# Loop with var max 6 and leave empty value if link is not clicked

Tags: jquery

With below code, url links are added on each click.

But, need to restrict to maximum of 6 urls. 
Also URL have to be initially like -  test.html?url1=&url2=&url3=&url4=&url5=&url6

if user clicked 2 items,

test.html?url1=google.com&url2=yahoo.com&url3=&url4=&url5=&url6

Remaining url3, url4, url5, url6 - will be empty value. Have to pass these url 6 parameters as POST script call to backend.

Thanks

**JS:**

```
var offerListing = [];
var favouriteOfferCookie = $.cookie('favouriteOffer');
var $cookieData;
if(!favouriteOfferCookie) {
  $cookieData = $.cookie('favouriteOffer', JSON.stringify(offerListing), { path: '/', expires: 7});
}
offerListing = $.parseJSON($.cookie('favouriteOffer'));

$('.favicon-wrapper').on('click', function(){
  if($(this).find('.favicon').hasClass('selected')){
    $(this).find('.favicon').removeClass('selected');
    console.log('Remove');
    var $offerLink = $(this).closest('.offer-list-item-wrapper').attr('href');
    offerListing = offerListing.filter((ol) => ol.link != $offerLink);
  } else{
    $(this).find('.favicon').addClass('selected');
    var $offerLink = $(this).closest('.offer-list-item-wrapper').attr('href');

    //Check if link exists before adding
    var linkExists = offerListing.find((ol) => {
      return ol.link == $offerLink
    });
    if (linkExists) {
      return;
    }
    offerListing.unshift(
      { 'link': $offerLink}
    );
    $.cookie('favouriteOffer', JSON.stringify(offerListing), { path: '/', expires: 7});
    offerListing = offerListing.slice(0, 6);
    console.log('Favourite Offer', offerListing);
    // format url array to string in "url1=https://url.com" format
    const formattedUrlArr = offerListing.map((elem, i) => `url${i + 1}=${elem.link}`);
    // join to create new url
    const newUrl = `${baseUrl}?${formattedUrlArr.join('&')}`;
    console.log('newUrl: ' +newUrl);
  }
});
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve].  There's too much unrelated code there (what has setting cookies got to do with parsing a string?).  Sure, you might save it there, but keep the code *relevant* to the question.